# How to destruct pair equivalence in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to destruct a pair equivalence hypothesis in proof when using Coq. But I didn't find the tactic for me.

The case is:

```
a, b, a', b' : nat
H0 : (a, b) = (a', b')
```

I want to destruct the pairs in H0 to generate

```
H1 : a = a'
H2 : b = b'
```

How can I achieve this? Which tactic should I use? Or should I define lemma for destructing such pair?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `injection H0` followed by `intros` as a first approximation.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in one step with `inversion H0`.

Comment: That works well. I still have a question: `inversion H0` also rewrites a to a' in my current goal. If I just want to split the hypothesis, how can I do that?